# ytplayer api event when reaching a position in a video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is there a way to cause an event when a video reaches a specific time? I want to get to a callback function at the time when the video has reached to a certain time, and the time it takes for the video to reach that time is unpredictable, since the user can skip part of the video, or buffering might take some time before the video resumes, or something like that, so simply setting a timed event wont work because the video might reach specific time earlier.

I can query the time of the video, but what I want is to get a callback when the video has reached a certain time. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to write the full code, but you should set up an interval, like this:

```
var time = 70; // Time in seconds, e.g. this one is one minute and 10 seconds
var reached = false;

var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(player.getCurrentTime() >= time && !reached) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        reached = true;
        timeReached();
    }
},1000);

function timeReached() {
    // Do what you have to
}
```

Comment: Reached is pointless, besides this is polling. It doesn't even solve the original problem. One second is quite a long time, but anyway if polling was what I wanted I wouldn't have asked. Thanks for trying.

Comment: This code calls `timeReached()` once the video has progressed the amount of seconds specified (`time`). `reached` is used so the callback function isn't ran more than one time, you can easily remove it. `player.getCurrentTime()` updates every second, so one second is not too much nor too less. I'm sorry to disappoint, could you elaborate on what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [Javascript wrapper for the YouTube player API](https://github.com/dmolsen/YoutubePlayer).

The API provides very simple event handling. E.g:

```
youtubePlayer.at('5000', function() {
    alert("You're five seconds into this Youtube clip");
});
```

Comment: It throws: Uncaught TypeError: youtubePlayer.at is not a function . can you please refer to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

use `player.getCurrentTime()`!

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_status